# Open connection to Webservice SOAP

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, soap, arduino

i have a SOAP webservice hosted on Google App Engine, and i need to send a soap service request by building full http packet request (my develop platform, Arduino ide, doesn't support any libraries for send soap request).
First of all i need to open a connection to my webservice, then send http request, but if i insert directly the address of webservice, i receive a message from OpenDns of bad request. 
How should i build my request? the problem seems to be that address of webservice doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access the WSDL of this hosted web service; simply by appending `?wsdl` to the web service URL.